# for mini laptop, is it better to install Windows XP or Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, laptop

i have mini laptop HP N280 Atom 1.6 with 2G memory

is it be better to install Windows XP  or  Windows 7  ?

what will work faster ?

thank's in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have an Acer Aspire One netbook and was wondering the same a while back and found this [review](http://eeepc.net/review-windows-7-on-the-acer-aspire-one/) of Windows 7, and a comparison of using XP, on the AA1 - this has the same processor as your machine but less RAM. The conclusion seems to be that W7 on that processor was fine and that there were very few hardware issues, but I'd see if you can find any notes for your specific computer.

Answer (score 0):

I would say XP would work "better" as a first thought but we have a Dell Inspiron 1210 with the same specs running Windows 7 Premium without issue.  You're going to get a faster response, etc with the XP software though.

Answer (score 0):

I ran W7 on a Atom 230 processor (533 FSB) and 2gb ram (DDR 533), it ran just fine with Aero enabled and transparency turned off, it ran even better with Aero disabled but I liked the Aero features and decided to suffer the performance hit besides it was not that much of one. Used it this way for a year before upgrading to an i5 PC recently.

I tried XP on it and saw no performance difference, in fact I believe W7 ran better so I stuck with W7.

.